# Bootstrap column and responsive issues (with multiple col-* per element)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 images which I want always perfectly centered within their div, but to behave differently based on screen width. Eg: on lg show the 3 across, md would be 2 and 1 below, sm would be all 3 vertically stacked.

I am trying to accomplish this by using Bootstrap's grid system but running into many issues, happy to hear how to fix with Bootstrap or any alternate solution.

```
<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><img src="image1.png" /></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><img src="image2.png" /></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4"><img src="image3.png" /></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

My issues are as follows:

**update** Both issues were solved by placing img-responsive & center-block in the img tags

1. Once they break (such as on md screen width) nothing becomes centered! I have tried using center-block and writing my own with float:none & margin: 0 auto but I get the same behavior. I've also tried putting each in a parent div with either of those options to no avail.
2. There's always some left margin on the leftmost image causing them to never be perfectly centered

Comment: Use these classes .img-responsive and .center-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is great for building responsive websites. Here's a solution that will centered the images within the fluid container div, while showing the 3 col layout on lg devices &  md showing 2 and 1 below, sm would be all 3 vertically stacked.

http://www.bootply.com/WEoEQo5a5f

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.thumbnail {
    border:none;
  }

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just going to have images in those `col-*-*` DIVs then use `text-align: center;`;

**HTML**

```html
<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/city/" /></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/city/" /></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/city/" /></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```css
div[class^="col-"] {
    text-align: center;
}
```

You might want to add your own CSS class rather than targeting the DIVs by the `col-*-*` classes like I did.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lactpch8/

Comment: Use Bootstrap's [`text-center`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) class.

Answer (score 0):

This is the modified version of above solution that use only Bootstrap classes for creating a 3 responsive image that work perfectly on various devices as per your need.
http://jsfiddle.net/Lactpch8/1/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="text-center">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/240/sports/2/" class="img-thumbnail text-hide" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="text-center">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/240/sports/" class="img-thumbnail text-hide" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="text-center">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/240/sports/1/" class="img-thumbnail text-hide" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```